# Predicate succeeds if each item from list L appears exactly once in the list U

Tags: list, prolog, unique

I need help in Prolog.

Write a predicate in Prolog which succeeds if each item from list `L` appears exactly once in the list `U`.

```
unique(L,U).
```

Comment: Please show your efforts. Do you know about select/3 etc.. ?

Comment: What if list L itself contains duplicates? In other words, what should `?- unique([a, b, a], [a, b, c, a]).` be?

Comment: yes!?- unique([a, b, a], [a, b, c, a]). this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways to do it (probably not the way this assignment intended to be solved):

```
unique(L, U) :-
    sort(L, Lunique),
    union(U, Lunique, X),
    msort(U, Usorted),
    msort(X, Xsorted),
    Usorted == Xsorted.
```

Let's try it:

```
?- unique([a, b], [a, b, c]).
true.

?- unique([a, b], [a, b, c, c]).
true.

?- unique([a, b], [a, a, b, c, c]).
false.

?- unique([b, a, c], [a, b, c, c]).
false.

?- unique([b, a, c], [a, b, c, e]).
true.
```

Tested in SWI Prolog and ECLiPSe CLP.

Comment: moreover, `unique([a,a,c],[a,b,c,d,d]) ?` succeeds too! :)